# How to attach additional file to NBug

Tags: c#, wpf, nbug

I'm using NBug to send reports from my WPF application, but I want to attach a client specific file to the email. Here is my code:

```
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += NBug.Handler.UnhandledException;
   Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += NBug.Handler.DispatcherUnhandledException;
   if (!File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory))
   {
       var stream = File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + FileNames.FILE_NAME_MACHINE_INFO);                
       stream.Close();
       TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + FileNames.FILE_NAME_MACHINE_INFO);
       tw.WriteLine("The very first line!");
       tw.Close();
    }
    NBug.Settings.AdditionalReportFiles.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + FileNames.FILE_NAME_MACHINE_INFO);
```

The problem is, that I get an exception

```
NBugError: An exception occurred while submitting bug report with Mail. Check the inner exception for details.
Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Mime.EightBitStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Base64Stream.FlushInternal()
   at System.Net.Base64Stream.Close()
   at System.Net.Mime.MimePart.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mime.MimeMultiPart.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at NBug.Core.Submission.Web.Mail.Send(String fileName, Stream file, Report report, SerializableException exception)
   at NBug.Core.Submission.Dispatcher.EnumerateDestinations(Stream reportFile, ExceptionData exceptionData)
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured the SMTP server for Nbug, either through code or app.config? The quickstart setting is `NBug.Settings.Destination1`

Comment: Yes, I configured it via app.config. When I don't want to attach the additional file, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I set the MiniDump Type to Full and the .zip file became more than 100MB and you can not send files so big with gmail. When I set the MinDump type to Tiny it solved the problem